# Meteor - publish and subscribe issue

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe

I am new to `Meteor` and trying to get publish and subscribe to work. Here is my code for subscribe:

```
//isClient
    Session.set("userSetLimit",10);

  Template.MoodList.helpers({
    hlpinvoices: function(){
        var curinvoices = Meteor.subscribe('invoices', Meteor.userId(),Session.get("userSetLimit"));
        return curinvoices;
    }
  });
```

publish:

```
//isServer
    Meteor.publish('invoices',function (creator,limit) {
        return Invoices.find({CreatedBy:creator},{sort:{DateCreated:-1}, limit:limit});
    })
```

and template:

```
  <template name="MoodList">
    <ul>
      {{#each hlpinvoices}}
        {{> invoice}}
      {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

And this is the error I got:

> Exception in defer callback: Error: {{#each}} currently only accepts
>   arrays, cursors or falsey values.

But if I use do:

```
//isClient
Session.set("userSetLimit",10);
  Template.MoodList.helpers({
    hlpinvoices: function(){
        return Invoices.find({CreatedBy:Meteor.userId()},{sort:{DateCreated:-1}, limit:Session.get("userSetLimit")});
    }
  });
```

I don't have problem. Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`subscribe` is something you call in order to get data from your server, it doesn't actually return any data itself - hence the error.  You'll want to call subscribe in the onCreated method of your template:

```
Template.MoodList.onCreated( function() {
  Meteor.subscribe('invoices', Meteor.userId(),Session.get("userSetLimit"));
});
```

Then in your helper you can return the invoices:

```
Template.MoodList.helpers({
    hlpinvoices: function(){
        return Invoices.find({CreatedBy:Meteor.userId()},{sort:{DateCreated:-1}, limit:Session.get("userSetLimit")});
    }
});
```

You can learn more about subscribing to data in the [Meteor Guide](http://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html#organizing-subscriptions). Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

`Meteor.subscribe` gives you subscription Id only .Try this

```
    Template.MoodList.helpers({
      hlpinvoices: function(){
        Meteor.subscribe('invoices', Meteor.userId(),Session.get("userSetLimit"));
        var curunnvoices=Invoices.find({CreatedBy:Meteor.userId()},{sort:{DateCreated:-1}, limit:Session.get("userSetLimit")}) 
       return curinvoices;
      }
   });
```